# Angular Material Select md-on-close Pass Parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angular-material

I would like to pass a parameter to a function with Angular Material Select md-on-close.

With my current code I get `undefined` returned when I do a console log.

What I have so far.

html

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Season</label>
    <md-select  name="season"
                ng-model="cteam.season"
                md-on-close="cteam.getid(season.$id)">

        <md-option ng-repeat="season in cteam.seasons | orderBy: 'name'" value="{{season.name}}">
            {{season.name}}
        </md-option>

    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

controller

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('CreateTeamController', function() {

            var vm = this;

            vm.getid = function(id) {
                console.log(id);
            };

        });
})();
```

Update (add app.js code)
app.js

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('app', [
            'ngRoute',
            'ngMaterial',
            'ngMessages',
            'firebase'
        ])
        .config(function($routeProvider, $mdThemingProvider){

            $mdThemingProvider
                .theme('default')
                .primaryPalette('deep-purple');

            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                })
                .when('/create/team', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/create-team.html',
                    controller: 'CreateTeamController',
                    controllerAs: 'cteam',
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/',
                });
        });

})();
```

Comment: Do you have your ng-controller directive in your view?

Comment: Yes I have ng-controller directive in my view. Its declare in my .config with $routeProvider

Comment: is it <ANY ng-controller="CreateTeamController as cteam"></ANY> ?

Comment: Added my app.js code. I'm sure its not my controller as I can get other stuff to work.

Comment: So in that ng-model="cteam.season" do you want to access variable that's in ng-repeat="season in seasons ... "?

Comment: Yes I want to access the variable that's in the ng-repeat. I want to access the $id property that each object has.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97454/discussion-between-user2759965-and-chris-hermut).

Answer (score 0):

See in `md-on-close="cteam.getid(season.$id)"` season does not refer to season that you use in your ng-repeat. ng-repeat creates a new scope and you are calling that function in it's parent scope.

But you are telling md-select that you want to bind 'selected' season to cteam.season in `ng-model="cteam.season"`.

All you have to do is to change your `md-on-close` attribute to `md-on-close="cteam.getId(cteam.season.$id)"` or whatever property you're referencing in your `ng-model`.

Comment: Still same result. I think the `md-on-close="cteam.getid()"` needs to know what key is being selected. I probably would have to change `ng-repeat="season in cteam.seasons` to `ng-repeat="(key, season) in cteam.seasons`